# iPhone display is (almost) identical for EL&U and ELL

Tags: discussion, design, mobile

I am bereft of my laptop. Until recently, a friend of mine had lent me his mini computer while my laptop gathered dust at a friend of a friend's house who had promised to fix it. The lender has reclaimed his itty-bitty computer, so now I am forced to use my secondhand iPhone 4 to surf on the Internet and I have made the following observation.

The banners for both sites  on my phone are virtually identical. Their titles get cut off at "English Language  & Us..." and "English Language Lear..." The colour themes are the same, the layout identical. It's no wonder new users are unaware of ELL's existence. You can't tell the difference!

Is this a well-known design defect? Because to my mind, it *is* a defect: users and visitors should be aware they are on two different sites. Considering that the number of mobile/cell/tablet users will increase over time, and PC users will decrease and eventually expire, I suggest this design issue should be swiftly  dealt with.

I have no idea if the same design 'feature' is evident on tablets or other devices which allow one to surf on the net.

EDIT
I've also noticed the following missing privilege features:
1) There  is no review queue.
2) I cannot see the number of upvotes and downvotes a post has received.
3) The number of visits a post has attracted is not displayed.
4) There is no editor 'toolbox' nor preview feature.

Finally, there is little difference between the normal text and a quoted excerpt. The latter appears indented on my display, whereas on a computer monitor, the citation is formatted more effectively.

Comment: Are you using the Stack Exchange app, or the website?

Comment: Website. Why, is there an app? Ahh, now I see there is an app to download at the bottom  of the page.

Comment: I cannot download it because i don't have the password for "icloud" nor "apple" the account belongs to a different owner. Oh bugger this!

Comment: OK. Mobile view. Yes, that is rather plain and cut down. But it's not a bug; it's a design issue.

Comment: Right, gottcha. Thanks for the headsup re the app.

Comment: The app isn't very different: it looks rather like the mobile view.

Comment: I've mentioned it to the design team; thanks for the feedback

Comment: I do not entrust this kind of repair to a 'friend of a friend'. Experience has shown me that when a repair is a favour, it tends to sink to the bottom of the repairer's priorities in life. Such an arrangement is almost guaranteed to generate ill feeling and resentment on both sides.

Comment: The themes for *all* mobile sites on the SE2.0 network are the same.  I find it unlikely that SE will fix this, but one could lodge a generalized [tag:feature-request] on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Off-topic comment, but followed up the conversation, the app is pretty useless, IMHO. Unwanted stuff on top, wanted moderation functions and more details, non-existent, and that just makes me to close the app every time and go back to the full website in Safari app to keep zooming in and out to review or flag, etc.

Comment: @anorton The point is that they don't have to be. It's only changing a few hex values (as I did to get my brown screenshot).

Comment: UPDATE: As of yesterday (Feb 8) I have my gorgeous laptop back, and the service was free of charge because I had to wait for so long!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spot the difference...

[image: ELU on mobile]
[image: ELL on mobile]

Perhaps we could have something which uses the colours of the main-site theme:

[image: ELU colours]

Comment: ThIs is exactly what I see but on my mobile screen the titles are cut off.