# What Just Happened?

Tags: support

I answered a question (on the non-meta ELU site) about the term "native speaker," after several other answers had been posted. Immediately everything is gone. Was the question deleted? Is my inability to find the question (and my answer) supposed to be my only clue to what happened? Why was it deleted (or whatever)?

Comment: If you have a link, I can tell you what happened. If you don't, you'll have to wait for a mod to answer. 10K+ users can see deleted content, but only if they know where it was in the first place. Only mods can search for deleted content, or browse from another user's profile to his deleted content.

Comment: @Dan Bron What should I provide a link to?

Comment: Tthe question or your answer or anything else in the thread. For example, if you have it open in another tab where it's saying "404" or something.

Comment: @Dan Bron No, I can find no sign of the whole shebang.

Comment: @Dan Bron Incidentally I thought I should delete the question, but (1) that might deny you points for answering, and (2) when I tried to delete it, I got a discouraging message. So I voted to close; but none of the four choices was "It was just too stupid." So I chose something else. What should happen to basically misguided questions like this one?

Comment: I can't delete your question. You could, before anyone answered, but questions where other people have answered and received votes can't be deleted unilaterally by the OP any longer. I'd say just don't worry about it. People mostly won't open it because it's marked "resolved". It doesn't hurt Meta to have a post about the "Network Profile" around. As a last resort though, if you really worry about having the question around, you could flag it with a custom flag asking a diamond mod to delete it. They may or may not accommodate the request, but they have the power.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue of now knowing where an answer was given instead of about the site feature of finding a deleted post.

Comment: @Hank I voted to close it too, and I wrote it. I'm sorry about the whole thing, but it seems like I'm not supposed to delete it once other people have answered. As I commented elsewhere, I wasn't sure what reason to give, or whether the reason matters.

Comment: @Chaim The comment is automatically added when you cast a vote to close with a custom reason. No worries.

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, did you answer using your smartphone? I find the two sites indistinguishable on my mobile phone, only the quality of the questions and seeing certain users tell me where I am. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/iphone-display-is-almost-identical-for-elu-and-ell

Comment: @Mari-Lou A No, I don't have a smart phone. I think I was just especially careless from tiredness.

Comment: This appears to be a valid and on topic question. Why is it closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question wasn't asked on EL&U, it was asked on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com), and you answered there:

> #### [What defines a native English Speaker?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/127265/10446)

It is not deleted. You didn't see it because you were simply looking on the wrong site.

A useful tool to know about is your [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/9754610/chaim?tab=activity), which can be used to find a timeline of all your activity across all sites on StackExchange.

You can find your network profile by clicking on your own username, then *Network Profile* in the top right near your gravitar.

Your activity timeline is the 4th tab on that page. It's worth bookmarking.

Comment: Thank you. All of that is very helpful, and it's obvious I've done something dumb. But what makes matters worse, I'm still not sure exactly what it was. Before I posted my question to ELU Meta (I think), I visited each site and clicked my user name. At ELL, my profile says "5 Answers" and lists five other answers I've given, but not that one. Why is that?

Comment: @Chaim The list of answers in your user profile for a given site lists your top 5 answers on that site sorted *by total score*. To see *all* your answers, you have to click one link deeper. Or you can sort the top 5 answers by recency instead of score.

Comment: At the "Mi Yodeya" site my profile says Answers (12). Then it lists a few followed by a link ("View more") to the whole list.

Comment: I don't know. Now the answer about native speakers is on the list of five. So I'm clearly too bewildered to proceed. Thanks for your help and good night.

Answer (score 2):

Your most recent ELU answer, deleted or otherwise, is [this one from the Ides of March](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/378565/2085).

There is no record of anything newer than that.

Comment: But I promise: there was a question about native speakers, and several interesting answers addressing it; I posted an answer that I still have in the Word document where I wrote it; and there's no sign of any of this at ELL or in my profile.

Comment: @Chaim Maybe your browser ate it, not ELU?

Comment: I responded to a question at ELU and then could not find the question or answer anywhere. Apparently I just overlooked it. Then, compounding my folly, I asked about it at EL&U meta instead of ELL meta. Dan Bron sorted it all out. Incidentally I then tried to remark on all of this to him, mistakenly clicked the comment link at your answer instead of his, and then found I could not delete the comment, only edit it to another comment long enough to post. Thus the zzz's. By the way I'm not proud of any of this, but I would be pleased to think that Chevy Chase might star in the film version.