# Could we have this header on the mobile site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, mobile

We have two versions of the header on the mobile version:

1. The standard main site one:

   [image: Standard site header]
2. And another one, visible in the [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) pages and [review queues](https://english.stackexchange.com/review)

   [image: alternative header]

Could the alternative header be made default?

Why:

- Easy access to reviews
- Link to the help pages
- Design consistency
- The fabulous ELU ampersand

The links to 'questions', 'tags' 'users', 'badges', and 'ask' could go below.

Edit: Hello there, [community mods](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11878/addressing-the-responsive-elu-site-theme-moving-forward)!

Comment: Related: [iPhone display is (almost) identical for EL&U and ELL](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/iphone-display-is-almost-identical-for-elu-and-ell) Jan, 2015

Comment: You could post a link on this question https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11878/addressing-the-responsive-elu-site-theme-moving-forward It *might* draw the CM's attention. Not today because it's a Sunday, and they have a life outside Stack Exchange. But then you never know, the CM could post an answer/reply later in the day.

Comment: I use the "full site" on my mobile - the "responsive" design (or whatever it's called) is actually much better than the mobile site in my opinion.

Comment: Shouldn’t this be migrated to Meta?

Comment: @ColleenV that's bad design then - the mobile site should be as good as the desktop

Comment: This is Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user This is specifically about ELU though, and we've had previous questions about our site design on our meta. See links shared by Mari-Lou above

Comment: Yes, but there is little, if nothing, ELU users can do about design or other features of the site,  as well as other sites. Meta is the place to ask...https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/introducing-the-custom-filter

Comment: The goal (as I understand it) is to maintain one design that works well for everything instead of having two designs that get out of sync in exactly the way you're complaining about. I don't think that's bad. Don't ask me about the aesthetics the new design inflicted on the sites though...

Comment: @ColleenV but that design should include usability for mobile users, especially nowadays.

Comment: @ColleenV There's three(ish) versions of the site being maintained at the moment.

Comment: My point is that the one design that is being actively maintained (as far as I can tell) works for phones, tablet, and computer screens for me. There's really no need to use the mobile version unless you prefer it. A lot of the functionality is much better with the "full site" on a phone than with the mobile site (in my opinion). If you don't like the full site on your mobile, I'm not going to argue with you, but I got the impression you may not have tried it.

Comment: @ColleenV yes, I have tried it (and have to for reviewing/flagging comments/viewing up- and downvotes on questions etc), but I prefer not having to zoom in the whole time. Sorry, not trying to be argumentative `:)`

Comment: You don't have to zoom on question and answer pages, just on the pages they haven't transitioned yet. some of the review tasks are difficult with it though

Comment: As far as I know, the mobile site is discontinued. No work has been done on it for a couple of years now, and any requests for changes will go unanswered. If you like it, you have to use it as it is. I'm pretty sure, although not certain, that this applies as much to the app itself as to what the app shows. (I personally use the app; I like it as a standalone tool that's independent of my web browser.)

Comment: @Jason awww what?

Comment: Read ["Stack Exchange should resume development on the mobile apps"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317690/stack-exchange-should-resume-development-on-the-mobile-apps).

Comment: @JasonBassford I think that is a different thing. I remember using the specific SE app for iPhone (or was it android?)  and thinking it was on the clunky side. I might be wrong about this, but there is 1. the mobile app that is no longer supported,  2. the mobile web site and 3. the new (ish)  responsive aka "full site".

Comment: The header belongs to the mobile site, you don't have to install anything. On the other hand, the app you had to download from the site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, perhaps. I haven't been aware of an actual website (not app) that's specific to mobile devices. I assume it has a different URL. Certainly with the new responsive site, a separate site seems counterintuitive.

Comment: @Jason yes, I'm talking about the website. You should be able to see what it looks like if you make the browser smaller.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Just making the size of browser window smaller is not the same thing as a *different* website that's used only by mobile devices. What you're describing is the main website that's acting in a responsive way to a smaller screen size. (Which would apply to a desktop computer with a smaller browser window just as much as it would to a mobile device with a smaller browser window.) If you're talking about the URL *english.meta.stackexchange.com*, that's the new responsive website.

Comment: @Jason Okay, I've just gone on the desktop version and tried resizing, and it turns out that wasn't what I was talking about. I can make it look like the mobile version if I [fake being a mobile](https://paste.pics/bc305a21f4ec6d13739fccdde737ca8e), but yes it is different. I actually prefer the way the site looks on a [tiny browser window](https://paste.pics/e93c2d42b5eac9b1cb6ebeea4982cb7b)...

Comment: You can always switch between the two using the links at the bottom of every page... If you're on the "full site" you will see a choice for "mobile". There is also a "Disable Responsiveness" link - not exactly sure what that does to every page.

Comment: @ColleenV you're amazing! Post it as an answer and I'll consider it solved

Comment: @ColleenV Very interesting! The URL is the same. So, the difference is more than *just* the size of the browser window—there is some essential difference in what's shown (regardless of screen size) depending on the perceived device being used to browse the URL. And I feel as if much of the confusion here (my own definitely included) has been due to terminology and semantics.

Comment: @Jason it's a mix of User agent and cookies, I assume.

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's still an unusual use of the term *mobile site*. I'm used to having *somesite.com* automatically redirect mobile devices (based on user agents as you say) to *mobile.somesite.com*, an *actually* different site.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The responsive design is significantly newer than the mobile design and is intended to replace it eventually. We're in a middle phase where both are options but we're not really developing for the mobile design. No sites have custom themes on mobile, they all use the default blue theme. :)

Comment: @Catija thanks! That's good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most pages in the full site work well on mobile with “responsiveness” enabled. You can always switch between the full site and the mobile site using the links at the bottom of every page. If you currently have the "full site" enabled you will see a choice for "mobile" and vice versa. There is also a "Disable/Enable Responsiveness" link.